# make pch symbols bigger in legend in R

Tags: r, legend, pch

Is there a way *ONLY* to make the pch symbols bigger using this piece of code? I cant seem to figure this out.

```
plot(1)
legend("topright", legend=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
       pch=c(20), col=c("red", "yellow", "green", "violet", "skyblue", "cyan"),
       title="number of studies", pt.cex=1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you expand your question? Running your current code doesn't plot anything.

Comment: I didnt think all the other code was important, but here you go.

Comment: Sorry, I should have reformulated that. I meant 'please provide some [minimal] code that shows the problem you're having. Extra resource: [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Heroka, The problem is that the legend pch dots are to small. I only want to increase those. If I run cex=1.5, the whole legend gets bigger. I_ONLY_want to increase pch setting in the legend.

Comment: Is there a reason pt.ces doesn't do the job? When I set it to 10 (or3) everything else remains unchanged

Comment: perfect Heroka, I didnt see the pt.cex function in legend. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Someone (OP or @Heroka) post `pt.cex` as a (short) answer?

Comment: if your question is only about one parameter of `legend`, there is no need to post all the code you have, you only need that which reproduces your problem in as few lines as possible

Comment: will do in the future rawr, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `pt.cex` inside legend to enlarge the points.